# I am trying to download email attachment from outlook in C#. its working with visual studio but not working when i am hosting to windows service/IIS

Tags: c#, iis, outlook, windows-services, office-automation

//This below line has some issue but i am unable to find the issue can anyone help me out or provide some alternate option to download the attachment
//outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)

```
Application outlookApplication = null;
NameSpace outlookNamespace = null;
MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
Items mailItems = null;

try
{
outlookApplication = new Application();
outlookNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);// Code is not executing from this line seems like some issue in this line
mailItems = inboxFolder.Items;

foreach (object collectionItem in mailItems)
{
MailItem newEmail = collectionItem as MailItem;
if (newEmail == null) continue;

if (newEmail.Attachments.Count > 0 && newEmail.UnRead)
{
for (int i = 1; i <= newEmail.Attachments.Count; i++)
{
string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\\Download\\1", newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(newEmail.Attachments[i].FileName);
if (file.Extension == ".xlsx" || file.Extension == ".xls")
{
newEmail.Attachments[i].SaveAsFile(filePath);
newEmail.UnRead = false;
}

}
}

}
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{

}
```

Comment: what goes wrong?

Comment: who is the logged in user when running under IIS . Docs :"Returns a Folder object that represents the default folder of the requested type for the current profile; for example, obtains the default Calendar folder for the user who is currently logged on."

Comment: I have added log to check where is the issue in my code but log is not going after this code 

inboxFolder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)

Comment: so you are getting an exception, what is it

Comment: No  exception is throwing

Comment: yes you are. if the code is stopping mid function thats an exception. Do `try{ bad statement }catch(Exception e){ log e.tostring()}`

Comment: That I tried . This code will work if i run  this in visual studio but it wont work if i use in windows service/Task scheduler .

Comment: did you read my second comment.

Comment: Please indent your code. Are you trying to test the patience of people who answer questions here?

Comment: I am using me as logged user

Comment: Basically, you can't run Office apps in a service.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am unable to figure out the issue of my code So I have posted the question .

Comment: No one asked why you posted the question... I asked why you don't indent your code, since it seems the least one can do to help people read your code so that they can understand it enough to answer. But in any case, you can't run Office apps in a service (IIS, Windows service), so this will never work anyway.

Comment: Any other alternate way to  download outlook attachment or link for Microsoft exchange

Comment: Your choices are EWS or Graph API.

Comment: If you keep in mind that there are indeed key differences between in Visual Studio and on IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3, then such issues are expected.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

If you need to access an Outlook store from a windows service you may consider using a low-level API on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI. Or just consider using any third-party wrappers around this API such as redemption.

In case of Exchange profiles consider using [EWS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) or [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/use-the-api).

Comment: Do you have any code snippet to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Take a look at the section in MSDN mentioned. There you will find code snippets.